# Cannot combine object array

Tags: javascript, web

Hello I am trying to combine two arrays but why the result only show the staff name and the rest is undefined?

```
let cuba2 = [];
let cuba3 = [];  
 
let staff = [
  {name:"tim", postcode:"68100",counter:0},
  {name:"sam", postcode:"43500",counter:0},
  {name:"apu", postcode:"55100",counter:0}
];

let cuba2 = [
  {fsm:"111", postcode:"68100"},
  {fsm:"222", postcode:"55555"},
  {fsm:"333", postcode:"66666"}
];

cuba2.forEach(data => {
  staff.forEach(assign => {
    if(data.postcode == assign.postcode{
      cuba3.push({
          fsm:data.FSM,
          postcode: data.POSCODE,
          staff:assign.name
      });
    }
  });
});
console.log(cuba3);
```

Comment: Can you please update your code to use a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/5648954)? Your code currently throws errors.

Comment: JavaScript is case senstitive, `data.POSTCODE` is different to `data.postcode`. You have lowercase keys, so you need to use lowercase property access

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I tried to put it all in one code but it did not work so thats why i posted like this. if only the ui is better to use than having to write one by one

Comment: @NickParsons you're a genius that you can read the code and help! thank you so much !

Comment: @muhammaddanish you could format the code in your text editor and paste it here already formatted.. I mean in case there's will to do it

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear from your code if you really wanted the result array to be the perfect join of the two input arrays using the key postcode for matching.

By the way that's what this demo attempts to achieve:

it loops through the two arrays `staff` and `cuba2`, producing a third array `cuba3` having items that have the same `postcode` and holding the `fsm` property from the `cuba` item and the `staff` property from the `staff` item:

```js
let staff = [
  {name:"tim", postcode:"68100",counter:0},
  {name:"sam", postcode:"43500",counter:0},
  {name:"apu", postcode:"55100",counter:0}
];

let cuba2 = [
  {fsm:"111", postcode:"68100"},
  {fsm:"222", postcode:"55555"},
  {fsm:"333", postcode:"66666"}
];

let cuba3 = [];  

//for each staffItem in staff
for(let staffItem of staff){  
  //for each cubaItem in cuba2
  for(let cubaItem of cuba2){
    //if an item in cuba2 was found matching staffItem.postCode
    if(cubaItem.postcode == staffItem.postcode)  {
      //push a new item in cuba3 with a mix of properties coming both from cubaItem and staffItem
      cuba3.push({
        fsm: cubaItem.fsm,
        postcode: cubaItem.postcode,
        staff: staffItem.name
      });
      //since the corresponding cubaItem was found, skip to the next iteration of staffItem
      continue;
    }
  }
}

console.log(cuba3);
/*
The result will be an array with lenght == 1
because the two sets will interesect only for postcode == '68100' 
[
  {
    fsm: "111"
    postcode: "68100"
    staff: "tim"
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it in two different ways.

1. You can loop through first array and inside that loop you can loop through the other array

```js
let cuba3 = [];  
 
let staff = [
  {name:"tim", postcode:"68100",counter:0},
  {name:"sam", postcode:"43500",counter:0},
  {name:"apu", postcode:"55100",counter:0}
];

let cuba2 = [
  {fsm:"111", postcode:"68100"},
  {fsm:"222", postcode:"55555"},
  {fsm:"333", postcode:"66666"}
];

cuba2.forEach(cuba => {
    staff.forEach(assign => {
        if (cuba.postcode == assign.postcode) {
            cuba3.push({
                fsm: cuba.fsm,
                postcode: cuba.postcode,
                staff: assign.name
            });
        }
    })
});

console.log(cuba3);
```

However the first one isn't very efficient. It has nested loops. We can use hashmaps (or objects) in JavaScript like the following:

```js
const cuba3 = [];  
 
let staff = [
  {name:"tim", postcode:"68100",counter:0},
  {name:"sam", postcode:"43500",counter:0},
  {name:"apu", postcode:"55100",counter:0}
];

let cuba2 = [
  {fsm:"111", postcode:"68100"},
  {fsm:"222", postcode:"55555"},
  {fsm:"333", postcode:"66666"}
];

const staffPostcodes = {};

for (let i=0; i < staff.length; i++) {
    staffPostcodes[staff[i].postcode] = staff[i].name;
}

for (let i=0; i < cuba2.length; i++) {
    if (!staffPostcodes[cuba2[i].postcode]) {
        continue;
    }

    cuba3.push({
        fsm: cuba2[i].fsm,
        postcode: cuba2[i].postcode,
        staff: staffPostcodes[cuba2[i].postcode]
    });
}

console.log(cuba3);
```

This one will output the same result but much faster when the array becomes very large.